# Python selenium .get doesnt finish

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:\\users\\Marcel\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.get("https://www.techwithtim.net/")
```

when I enter the upper lines as a test the `driver.get` does open the page but it doesn't step through the `.get` function.

Anyone have a tip?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it doesn't step through*" the function?

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause will be the loading taking very long. Seleium `driver.get` will wait for the loading to completely finish (with the exception of AJAX contents), thus if your website is not optimized or your internet is not good, it is possible for the code to be stuck at `.get` for some time.
A simple way to test everything else is working is just to get a known website, like google.com.